# how to reverse the strings in one of the column in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, reverse

I want all the entries in the name column reversed and stored in another column in SQL SERVER 2008. 
I do not want to use the string reverse function.
I want to do it using loops.

```
name         reversename
----------   ----------
john         nhoj
kevin        nivek
paul         luap
```

table structure-
contractor (contractno, name, email, phoneno)

I want only the  entire name column in reverse order.

I HAVE TRIED THIS

```
DECLARE @revString VARCHAR(55)=''
DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(55)= (SELECT NAME FROM CONTRACTOR)

DECLARE @ln INT=LEN(@string2)

WHILE @ln > 0
BEGIN
    SET @revString = @revString + SUBSTRING(@string2, @ln, 1)
    SET @ln= @ln - 1
END
SELECT @string2, @revString,@ln
```

Found a solution using loops too

```
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @REVERSE TABLE(
Name    VARCHAR(MAX),
ReverseName  VARCHAR(MAX))
DECLARE NAME_CURSOR CURSOR FOR 
SELECT DISTINCT NAME FROM CONTRACTOR
OPEN NAME_CURSOR 
FETCH NEXT FROM NAME_CURSOR
INTO
@NAME

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN

    DECLARE @revString VARCHAR(55)=''
    DECLARE @string2 VARCHAR(55)= @NAME
    DECLARE @ln INT=LEN(@string2)

    WHILE @ln > 0
    BEGIN
            SET @revString = @revString + SUBSTRING(@string2, @ln, 1)
            SET @ln= @ln - 1
    END
    INSERT INTO @REVERSE VALUES (@string2, @revString)
    FETCH NEXT FROM NAME_CURSOR INTO @NAME
END
SELECT * FROM @REVERSE
CLOSE NAME_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE NAME_CURSOR
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem.  Have you tried something yet?  By the way, SQL Server isn't the best place to be doing this.  It would be easier to do from an app language like C# or Java.

Comment: assigned a task in SQL Server only @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: There's a REVERSE function...  select REVERSE('john')

Comment: as mentioned in the question, i do not want to use the reverse function. @JohnPasquet

Comment: If there is a built in function to do this, you should use it (REVERSE) any method you build with loops will be less performant, complex and therefore more difficult to maintain. What have you tried? If assigned you a task to do this and you came back with  a loop I would ask you to rewrite using REVERSE!

Comment: @DhruvilShah But *why* do you not want to use it - Was it a specification of the homework assignment?

Comment: @Jamiec it is the part of the assignment to not use the inbuilt function.

Comment: @DhruvilShah Right, so as this is an assignment you need to have an attempt first, and if you get stuck post the code you've tried and someone will help you - but we don;t do your homework for you!

Comment: i already tried, but the thing is i am able to take only one string to reverse, i want to know how to take the entire column values instead of one value. @Jamiec

Comment: Hint: use a tally table.

Comment: @DhruvilShah first you need to put some effort in and show us what you have tried. You will have to use a built in function of some sort e.g. RIGHT() you might want to look at Numbers/Tally table.

Comment: Aside from all other facts - asking you to do this in a loop teaches you pretty much nothing except the *wrong* way to approach a task like this. CS teaching annoys me!

Comment: have posted the code i tried @Jamiec

Comment: @SteveFord Added the code i tried

Comment: @DhruvilShah Your code works if you add `select top 1 name`  instead of `select name`. Your code is written to reverse a single input parameter. If you want to use it over a table, create a function and use that.

Comment: I want to do it using loop and without function.
And i want all the values in the column to be reversed. @SqlZim

Comment: @DhruvilShah Then you could use a cursor and use your looping code inside the cursor (which is also a loop).

Comment: @SqlZim I exactly want to know how to use that.

Comment: @DhruvilShah https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-cursor-transact-sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, clearly a homework assignment.  Syntax and techniques aside, the **take-away** here is that you should **REALLY** avoid loops when possible... think data sets.

Consider the following

1) Subquery B1 will create a record for each character in the string by using an ad-hoc tally table.  A tally/numbers table would do the trick as well.  The internal/temporary results would look like this:

[image]

2)  The XML Path portion in the Cross Apply B will consolidate the records in DESCENDING order of N

**Example**

```
    Declare @YourTable Table ([name] varchar(50))
    Insert Into @YourTable Values
     ('john')
    ,('kevin')
    ,('paul')

Select A.Name 
      ,ReverseName = B.NewString
 From @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select NewString = Stuff((Select '' +C 
                  From (
                        Select N,C = substring(A.Name,N,1)  
                         From (Select Top (len(A.Name)) N=Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select NULL)) From master..spt_values ) A1
                       ) B1
                  Order By N Desc
                  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value('(./text())[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
                  ,1,0,'')
             ) B
```

**Final Results**

[image]

Comment: worked quite well, but facing problems where there is a space in the column value.

Comment: added a pic in your answer. Check it out

Comment: @DhruvilShah Here is the image you wanted to link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztybn.png

Comment: change `For XML Path ('')),1,0,'')` to `For XML Path (''), type).value('.','nvarchar(max)'),1,0,'')`

Comment: @SqlZim fyi.  It has been reported for a nudge more performance ... (./text())[1] ....  However, I have yet to see any stats.  Nor have I had the ambition to test it.  :)

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Interesting, I'll have to take a look at that.

Comment: @SqlZim Be sure to let me know.  I know you are all about the bechmarks.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti Brad Schulz is a reliable source, and I see his comment here: [Handling special characters with `for xml path('')` - Rob Farley](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/rob_farley/archive/2010/04/15/handling-special-characters-with-for-xml-path.aspx). But it would be nice to know where that information came from.

Comment: Thank you guys, it worked very well!! @JohnCappelletti 
I actually found one more solution using the loops on my own, if you want to have a look!! Cheers!!

Comment: thnaks @SqlZim the change solved the problem cheers!!

Comment: I am not able to find where i can post my own answer here!! @JohnCappelletti

Comment: @DhruvilShah No worries.  They closed the question.  But seriously, avoid the loops when possible.  I was amazed at the performance differance between my looping parse function vs a set-based approach.   Cheers :)

Comment: yes thank you @JohnCappelletti I totally understood what you are trying to say, also observed that the time taken to run the loop one is very high when compared to the other, but using loop was compulsory as a part of my assignment!! Thanks a lot :) Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

This is using a kind of loop by joining with a tally table and concatenation the values in reversed order.

```
DECLARE @test table(name varchar(10))
INSERT @test values('John'),('Tom Jones')

;WITH N(N)AS 
(
  SELECT 
    1
  FROM(VALUES(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))M(N)
),
tally(N)AS
(
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY N.N)
  FROM N,N a,N b,N c,N d,N e,N f
)
SELECT
  *
FROM
  @test t
CROSS APPLY
(
  SELECT
    ( 
      SELECT z
      FROM 
        (SELECT substring(name, N, 1) z, N
         FROM tally
         WHERE n < =LEN(name)) t1 
      ORDER BY N DESC
      FOR xml path(''), type 
  ).value('.', 'varchar(max)') z
) y
```

Comment: Plus 1 for a non-looping solution AND in protest of the punitive downvotes we got.  Regardless of the fact that this was a homework assignment with ridiculous constraints, OP was going down the wrong path

Comment: @JohnCappelletti already upvoted you. I don't see why a good answer should be punished for an odd question

Comment: Thank you, but certainly not necessary, and I agree with you.  With the possible exception of Gordon Linoff (whom I suspect was genetically engineered), we all went through a learning process.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti my upvote had nothing to do with this pathetic downvoting. I upvoted you right away. Was working on a similar answer(as you can see) when you posted before me.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti there is even a badge for getting 3 upvotes for an answer   with 3 downvotes. So the downvoter is way off

Answer (score -1):

Create this function

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[revString] (@input VARCHAR(250))
RETURNS VARCHAR(250)
AS BEGIN
DECLARE @strCount int;
DECLARE @revStr varchar(250) ='';
declare @cnt int ;
set @strCount = LEN(@input);
set @cnt= @strCount;

While @cnt>0
    begin
        set @revStr= @revStr +  substring(@input,@cnt,1);
        set @cnt =@cnt-1;
    end 
RETURN @revStr
END
```

select dbo.revString('ASSDE') --Results (EDSSA)